# AngularJS breaking Foundation modals. Workaround?

Tags: css, angularjs, zurb-foundation

Anyone know the proper way to handle Foundation4 modals when using AngularJS? When I  link out of a modal to a new view, the new view loads and the div of the modal disappears, but the page remains darkened as if its still hidden behind a modal that has already exited, and I can't click on anything. I attempted to make the  with a class attribute "close-reveal-modal", but that just makes the link element disappear.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Generally, if you have complex third party javascript widgets, you need to wrap them inside a directive, so that the changes are applied within the angular digest cycle.

Comment: Thanks. I also saw that online but was hoping that wasn't the case.

Comment: hm and what DOM element has attached that modal? Is it element of angular view?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this as well.  I created a plugin to deal with it (and a couple of other common foundation controls).

Check out:

[xdotcommer/angular-foundation](https://github.com/xdotcommer/angular-foundation)

The usage is a little specific to my needs (I add some content inside the modal), but you should be able to copy the modal.js and modal.html and make it work.

I know I'm not *supposed* to use jQuery, but I did bind to the click event to execute `$('#modal').foundation('reveal', 'open')` - it was easier than figuring out the magic they were doing at the time.